# Show app running time in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I would like to write a counter that shows how many seconds an app has be running for. (textView) and the counter should be cumulative and starts from where it left off. Im new to iphone sdk.

Answer (score 0):

you are going to have to do these things:

get the time when the app starts in [applicationDidFinishLaunching:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW18) in your application delegate

check if you have an old time using [NSUserDefaults](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmac%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2Fcocoa%2Freference%2Ffoundation%2FClasses%2FNSUserDefaults_Class%2Findex.html&ei=SJ0VTKCDIMzJcZWQ3fML&usg=AFQjCNHLQXIcOakA_VvDKfSYMxmHch2NxA&sig2=94Z0Wl-d3RIGUGA9EyBb9w)

have a thread that updates the ui (your textView display, may i suggest using a label instead) with the ever increasing time using [NSThread](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmac%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2Fcocoa%2Freference%2Ffoundation%2FClasses%2FNSThread_Class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=aJ0VTJScNIvBcYWy0bwM&usg=AFQjCNGcS60oS0HUsHEGSNH32IjrQSbKOQ&sig2=FyFZAfzoZ9exKMoId604Ew) or [NSTimer](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CCkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fiphone%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2Fcocoa%2Freference%2Ffoundation%2FClasses%2FNSTimer_Class%2FReference%2FNSTimer.html&ei=ep0VTN6BO8jXcfG79bIM&usg=AFQjCNEGfRtEz4OZLBCyydfdJJFCckrXwg&sig2=aeFPFGqRnWvdzW8IeyHkAw) - i recommend NSThread. you will also need to perform your [updates on your ui thread](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) as updating your ui from a background thread can just get lost in the post.

store the end time in [applicationWillTerminate:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW28) in your application delegate using [NSUserDefaults](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fmac%2Flibrary%2Fdocumentation%2Fcocoa%2Freference%2Ffoundation%2FClasses%2FNSUserDefaults_Class%2Findex.html&ei=SJ0VTKCDIMzJcZWQ3fML&usg=AFQjCNHLQXIcOakA_VvDKfSYMxmHch2NxA&sig2=94Z0Wl-d3RIGUGA9EyBb9w)

lots of googling ahead of you, have fun!